# CanJS + jQuery + Twitter Bootstrap for a PhoneGap App?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, cordova, canjs

I'm wondering what technologies to use to build a Single Page Application on PhoneGap, my team has experience on CanJS and we are discussing about DOM Manipulation and UI Components.

I don't know what to use, if jQuery or jQuery Mobile, I think that jQ only purpose will be DOM manipulation, I don't think that we use jQM way to load pages, having CanJS, but I'm afraid of missing "mobile friendly DOM manipulation" like touch, gestures and so...

I think Bootstrap it's better option for components, thinking in the scenario that we will build the App for tablets (iPads, Android sizes...) and a "Desktop Web" version after that, so, maybe jQM is too mobile for the Desktop version.

What do you think about that? jQ or jQM? 
if jQM is better option, it won't collide in functionality with Bootstrap, I have the sense that jQM is half webapp framework half UI framework/components?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small lib some time ago that bridges between CanJS and jQuery Mobile, it was not updated since then, but it's really short and it can give you an idea how to glue these two together https://github.com/retro/Tonfa.js/blob/master/tonfa.js

Also, depending on your app, you might not need the whole jQuery mobile, maybe a touch event lib / plugin for jQuery would be enough.

If you are interested in using jQuery mobile and CanJS together and you think Tonfa.JS might help you add an issue and I'll do an update for the latest versions.